# How to display products on FE in TYPO3 6.0.4

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Thanks in Advance.....

I am getting problems in TYPO3 6.0.4

1. **to make display products on FE which are already added in BE in TYPO3 6.0.4.**
2. **how to set enable TypoScript Templates in TYPO3 6.0.4 which are not present in BE while installing the shop.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TypoScript` templates by editing your main `TypoScript` template.

You most likely need to add a frontend plugin for whatever shop system you use.

The handbook of the extension should tell you more.